# Running 14/2 Romex vertically up a concrete wall

Tags: electrical, wiring, concrete, code-compliance

I'm in western NY.

I have an outlet in my unfinished basement that I need to connect to the electric panel. I have the 14/2 cable wired into the outlet and I just need to run it up the concrete wall, around the wood at the ceiling, and into the panel.

The vertical distance on the concrete wall is about five feet. The space around the outlet is a very low traffic area. There are no kids around, and the cats aren't much interested in the electrical boxes, receptacles, outlets, or cables. I can't see anyone going within 4 or 5 feet of the outlet except to plug something in on rare occasions. I expect most things (work laptop, monitor, phone charger, and digital picture frame) to be plugged in and to stay there.

What's the NEC2023 (and state code) way to run that cable? Do I have to buy metal conduit for the five foot distance up the wall? Or am I OK to attach with some sort of concrete screw+anchor once or twice along that five foot vertical span and then transition to wire staples around the wood to the panel?

Answer (score 2):

Most LAHJs consider it exposed to damage, so some form of protection is required.

That could be schedule 80 PVC conduit. It does not need to be metal. That could be a board. Typically it needs to extend to the ceiling, or 7-8 feet above the floor, whichever is less. Whether it's 7 or 8 feet (and, indeed, what, exactly, is "exposed to damage") unfortunately (for the sake of clarity) varies with LAHJ rather than being actually in the NEC.

Comment: I would very much like to be in line with local code requirements. Trouble is that I can't find anything like a city or state electrical code. There are ways to look at sections of NFPA70 / NEC2023 for free in at least one place, yet my continued efforts have not yielded anything similar for the state of New York, the town of Irondequoit, or the city of Rochester. Is there a central repository for this sort of thing, or do I have to go digging in the city and state websites?

Comment: In most cases states/cities adopt NFPA70 with some local amendments, and things like "exposed to damage" is usually still left to the discretion of the inspector - but the common interpretation of that is as stated in the answer. You could try "up.codes" if they've done your area (not affiliated, have used it some times.) That claims unamended NFPA 70, 2017, for the state. NYC may have it's own special deal, Ra-cha-cha might well just follow the state. https://up.codes/codes/new_york

Comment: @THill3, you buy official versions of the NY CRR from a book publisher. The unofficial Westlaw one [references](https://govt.westlaw.com/nycrr/Document/I4658cb00969111ea8139bdadf90e6f85) RCNYS. See [RCNYS E3401.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/NYSRC2020P1/chapter-34-general-requirements#NYSRC2020P1_Pt08_Ch34_SecE3401.1) for your electrical code. It's NFPA 70, which is the NEC. Local municipalities, counties, etc. can amend things, so you would have to go rummaging through sub-jurisdictions of NYS for any such amendments.

Comment: @THill3, to be in line with local code requirements, you would have an electrical permit for the work, and the issuing office should be able to tell you how you could find answers to your code questions. It varies quite a lot, from one place to another, Where I am, any exposed "Romex"-type wiring is prohibited.